# Move files having only 2 lines in AIX

Tags: file, find, aix, mv, wc

I have a list of files and I want to move to another directory those that contain only two lines.

Is there a way to do it in a single command?

I am on AIX 7.1.

Comment: Utility `wc(1)` might be useful with option `-l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "a single command", which is an unusual requirement. Generally speaking, you could use `find` or a `for` loop over a wildcard:

- with `find`:

  ```
  find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do [ $(wc -l < "$f") -eq 2 ] && mv -- "$f" /target/dir/; done' findshell {} +
  ```
- with `for`:

  ```
  for f in ./*; do [ -f "$f" ] && [ $(wc -l < "$f") -eq 2 ] && mv -- "$f" /target/dir; done
  ```

If you instead have a list of files, perhaps with ksh93 and an array variable -- `files=( * )`, for example -- you could loop over those filenames:

```
for f in "${files[@]}"; do [ -f "$f" ] && [ $(wc -l < "$f") -eq 2 ] && mv -- "$f" /target/dir; done
```

In the `find` solution, we limit the results to "file" types; for each of those, we execute a shell with as many arguments as will fit (the `{} +` part of the syntax); that shell is given 'findshell' as ARG[0], simply as a placeholder. The rest of the arguments are examined in the inner `for` loop; those that have exactly two lines are moved.

In the `for` solutions, we loop over the resulting file list and check to ensure we're looking at a regular file `[ -f "$f" ]` and that the file contains exactly two lines. If both of those conditions match, we move the file.

In all of the `mv` cases, we explicitly end the options using `--` before giving the filename so that filenames that happen to begin with a `-` dash are not unintentionally mistaken as options. This is also why the manual `for` loop uses `./*` as the wildcard, so that all of the expanded filenames start with `./`, preventing those filenames from starting with a dash.